# Date diff count function not able to update to database

Tags: php, sql, date, datediff

I am trying to update date difference to sql database, when i output `echo $foo` it shows me the output, when i try to `UPDATE` into database it is not updating and the value is `0`. the Column is `total INTEGER(4)`

I tried the string directly on the SQL statement `total = '53'` - it works
I even tried a string on variable `$foo = '24'` - it works
Using the function is not `UPDATING`.

```
$startingDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fm_startingdate']);
$endingDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fm_endingdate']);

$foo = timeTotal($startingDate, $endingDate);
function timeTotal($dT1, $dT2){
    $d1 = new DateTime($dT1);
    $d1->sub(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    $d2 = new DateTime($dT2);
    $diff = $d1->diff($d2);
    echo $diff->days;
}

echo $foo // 53

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    $sql = "UPDATE terms SET
            name = '$termNameTrimmed',
            startingdate = '$startingDate',
            endingdate = '$endingDate',
            total = '$foo' // <-- this is not updating as expected
            WHERE term_id = '$termId'";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Updated Successfully!";
        header("Location: ../../term_months.php".$URLId);
    }
    else {
        echo "Records are NOT Added. Please try again<br />";
        echo mysqli_error ($con);
    }
}
else{
    $_SESSION['exists'] = "<strong>".$termNameTrimmed."</strong> name is already exists!";
    header ("Location: ../../term_month_edit.php".$URLId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your function, it does not return anything, but echo, try instead:

```
$foo = timeTotal($startingDate, $endingDate);
function timeTotal($dT1, $dT2){
    $d1 = new DateTime($dT1);
    $d1->sub(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    $d2 = new DateTime($dT2);
    $diff = $d1->diff($d2);
    return $diff->days; // no echo but return 
}

echo $foo // 53
```

Hint: for debugging use a string in front of the result:

```
  echo "\$foo:". $foo;
```

in your case it will echo
$foo:0